# nesting form element names for objects

Tags: html, forms, http-post

I have a page where I need to submit an unknown number of objects with this structure:

```
object
  name
  phone
  hours
    monday
      open
      close
    tuesday
      open
      close
    ...etc
```

I am trying to figure out how to use the name parameter on my html element to create these objects.  The problem is, they do not necessarily have to have all of the attributes.  Some may have phone numbers, some may not....same with the hours.  Everything I have tried results in something like this

```
Array ( [params] => Array ( [service[name] => Array ( [0] => service5 [1] => service5 ) [service[phone] => Array ( [0] => 1234 [1] => 12345 ) ) )
```

Is there any way to do this?

UPDATE:  The only way I have been able to come up with is to figure out a way to use an index like this:

```
params[service][1][name]
```

I will have to use javascript to generate/update that index anytime an object is added or removed from the page...

Is there any way to achieve this object packaging dynamically?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using javascript you can pull all the values and generate a [JSON](http://www.json.org) string, the send that to the server and maintain your layered type array.

Comment: This is part of a rails form...  That is a good idea I just have to figure out how to achieve it utilizing rails....  Thanks

Comment: Here is an [article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/04/inside-ruby-on-rails-serializing-ruby-objects-with-json/) describing Rails with JSON

Comment: Thanks!  I will review this and if it works properly for me I will accept your answer :)